# R: x12 package - how should I add user defined regressors

Tags: r, arima, x12

I want to use certain user-defined regressors with x12 In R. 
Syntax tried:

```
 x12(setP(new("x12single",ts=tso),list(r gression.variables=c("xyz","lpyear"))))
```

What type should be xyz (should it be time series object or a column in dataframe)?

> Error: regression variable name "xyz" Not found. Error in readx12Out(file,freq_series=frequency(tso),start_series=start_series: Error! No proper run of x12! Check your parameter settings.

Thanks